# Byte() to unsigned integer in .NET

Tags: vb.net, bytestream

I have been trying my hand at handling packets and bytes for the first time, and I have not been able to obtain the packet length correctly so far after many different techniques.

#### Code:

```
Public Shared Sub Client(packet As Packet)
    Console.WriteLine( _ 
      "Client -> " & _
      packet.Timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff") & _
      " length:" & Convert.ToString(packet.Length))

    'Define Byte Array
    Dim clientPacket As Byte() = packet.Buffer

    ' Open a Binary Reader
    Dim memStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(clientPacket)
    Dim bReader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(memStream)

    ' Remove the Ethernet Header
    Dim ethBytes As Byte() = bReader.ReadBytes(14)

    ' Remove the IPv4 Header
    Dim IPv4Bytes As Byte() = bReader.ReadBytes(20)

    ' Remove the TCP Header
    Dim TCPBytes As Byte() = bReader.ReadBytes(20)

    ' Get the packet length
    If clientPacket.Length > 54 Then
        Dim len As UInt32 = bReader.ReadUInt32
        Console.WriteLine(len)
    End If
End Sub
```

So far, all of my attempts at having the console write the data length have resulted in failure. I validated the endianness and actually wrote out the bytes to verify that I was handling the correct data.

Example bytes:

00 00 00 24 -> UINT32 is 36 bytes, but I am getting an array of Integers like 3808493568

How can I fix this?

Comment: It is big-endian, you need to reverse the bytes.

Comment: It returns the data length plus the header lengths for the three data layers. I am using WinPCAP by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Hans, endianness is your problem. Also, I'd recommend you use the `BitConverter` class on the `clientPacket` array, easier than using streams.

```
Dim len As UInt32
Dim arr() As Byte
arr = {0, 0, 0, 24}
len = BitConverter.ToUInt32(arr, 0)
Console.Write(len.ToString) 'returns 402653184

arr = {24, 0, 0, 0}
len = BitConverter.ToUInt32(arr, 0)
Console.Write(len.ToString) 'returns 24
```

For your code, I think this might work (untested):

```
If clientPacket.Length > 54 Then
  Dim lenBytes As Byte() = bReader.ReadBytes(4)
  Array.Reverse(lenBytes, 0, 4)
  Dim len As UInt32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(lenBytes, 0)
```